# Putting questions into a list and randomly selecting them

Tags: python, tkinter

I've had this problem for a while where my quiz won't work, where certain tkinter windows wouldn't close even though the code was there. However, after speaking to my teacher, he said that it was possible to read my text file to get the questions and answers, then place them in a list so that I could randomly select them to be displayed in the window (That way no question appears twice). He then said that you could have the window refresh after each question is answered, putting a different question up with different answers (Maybe even a "Correct"/"Wrong" inbetween each question). If anyone has an idea how to do ths is would be a massive help. Thanks.

```
def quiz_easy():

    global question 
    questions = []
    correctanswers = []
    possibleanswer1s = []
    possibleanswer2s = []
    possibleanswer3s = []
    easy_questions = open("sup.txt", "r")

    count = 1
    for line in easy_questions:
        if count == 1:
            questions.append(line.rstrip())
        elif count == 2:
            correctanswers.append(line.rstrip())
        elif count == 3:
            possibleanswer1s.append(line.rstrip())
        elif count == 4:
            possibleanswer2s.append(line.rstrip())
        elif count == 5:
            possibleanswer3s.append(line.rstrip())
        if count == 5:
            count = 1
        else:
            count = count + 1 

    print(questions)
    print (correctanswers)

    randno1 = random.randint(0,len(questions)-1)
    master = Tk()
    text = Text(master)
    text.insert(INSERT, questions[randno1])
    text.insert(END, "?")
    text.pack()
    text.tag_add("here","5.0", "1.4")
    text.tag_add("start", "1.8", "1.13")
```

Comment: It sounds like you're asking us to do your homework for you. Do you have a _specific_ question about this problem you want us to answer?

Comment: Why are you using `global`??

Comment: @BryanOakley No. I am not doing my homework. This is for a program I am writing in which I am getting help from my teacher. I am trying to make a quiz.

Answer (score 0):

Think OOP intead of sequencial

Your Quiz should be a class.

Avoiding MVC approach, stay simple the class directly handle the UI, the data and the process.

The constructor read the question file and update your internal data representation (That may be reworked too), and start the Root Tk instance

Create a method to display the question (a Label) and the area dedicated to the answer (an Entry)
Add a button "OK" or bind the  key on the Entry widget to start a method dedicated to the control of the answer and displaying of the correct answer

Create this method

Add a method for the Tkinter mainloop

In the main of the script instanciate the quizz, call the method "display a question" and then call the method for mainloop()

We are waiting for your code ;-) to assist

tips: 1: Prefer:

```
import Tkinter as tk  # instead of from Tkinter import * to keep your code explicit.
```

2: Forget the global directive in your code .. non sense here
3: the file reading is rought, the format of your file is not optimised.
 to not going too quickly in XML paradygm .. 
  think about prefix ruler

```
QUE translate pig in french
COR cochon
ALT proc
ALT truie
ALT verrat
ALT porcelet
ALT cochonet
ALT gorret
ALT nourrin
ALT nourrain
ALT cochette
```

for each line you just append a possible answer in a list of possible answers

Ready to run your brain ... go. ^^